# Getting java.lang.StackOverflowError() while trying to Delete Data in Azure Deltalake via Synapse Notenook

Tags: azure-synapse, delta-lake

There are some threads on Stackoverflow which have suggested solutions to resolve java.lang.StackOverflowError(), I have tried all the suggested solutions but none worked and also none of them talks about this issue from the deletion aspect. That's why I have opened a new question.

**Context Behind the Issue:**
I have a notebook in Azure Synapse to fill the fact tables in DWH. A very high-level logic is this: After processing the data from the source the notebook looks if there are any common records between source & target side based on two-columns, if records exists then it deletes all of them and then insert the new records. This notebook is generic for a lot of clients and hence it is triggered atleast 4 times a day from a pipeline.

**Issue I am Facing**
I have attached the error stack trace below. It has always been the case (till now) that whenever I got below error just re-running the notebook fixes it. But this time I am stuck with it for 2 days straight.

**Error**

```
An error occurred while calling o5686.delete.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.jobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:651)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.$anonfun$writeFiles$1(TransactionalWrite.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:391)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.DeleteCommand.$anonfun$rewriteFiles$2(DeleteCommand.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.DeltaProgressReporter.withJobDescription(DeltaProgressReporter.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.DeltaProgressReporter.withStatusCode(DeltaProgressReporter.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.DeltaProgressReporter.withStatusCode$(DeltaProgressReporter.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.DeleteCommand.withStatusCode(DeleteCommand.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.DeleteCommand.rewriteFiles(DeleteCommand.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.DeleteCommand.performDelete(DeleteCommand.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.DeleteCommand.$anonfun$run$2(DeleteCommand.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog.withNewTransaction(DeltaLog.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.DeleteCommand.$anonfun$run$1(DeleteCommand.scala:114)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordFrameProfile(DeltaLogging.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordFrameProfile$(DeltaLogging.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.DeleteCommand.recordFrameProfile(DeleteCommand.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.$anonfun$recordDeltaOperationInternal$1(DeltaLogging.scala:133)
    at com.microsoft.spark.telemetry.delta.SynapseLoggingShim.recordOperation(SynapseLoggingShim.scala:95)
    at com.microsoft.spark.telemetry.delta.SynapseLoggingShim.recordOperation$(SynapseLoggingShim.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.DeleteCommand.recordOperation(DeleteCommand.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperationInternal(DeltaLogging.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLogging.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation$(DeltaLogging.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.DeleteCommand.recordDeltaOperation(DeleteCommand.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.DeleteCommand.run(DeleteCommand.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:560)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$1(Dataset.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.AnalysisHelper.toDataset(AnalysisHelper.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.AnalysisHelper.toDataset$(AnalysisHelper.scala:87)
    at io.delta.tables.DeltaTable.toDataset(DeltaTable.scala:44)
    at io.delta.tables.execution.DeltaTableOperations.$anonfun$executeDelete$1(DeltaTableOperations.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.AnalysisHelper.improveUnsupportedOpError(AnalysisHelper.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.AnalysisHelper.improveUnsupportedOpError$(AnalysisHelper.scala:91)
    at io.delta.tables.DeltaTable.improveUnsupportedOpError(DeltaTable.scala:44)
    at io.delta.tables.execution.DeltaTableOperations.executeDelete(DeltaTableOperations.scala:41)
    at io.delta.tables.execution.DeltaTableOperations.executeDelete$(DeltaTableOperations.scala:41)
    at io.delta.tables.DeltaTable.executeDelete(DeltaTable.scala:44)
    at io.delta.tables.DeltaTable.delete(DeltaTable.scala:234)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.flowAnalysis(CodeContext.java:535)
    at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.flowAnalysis(CodeContext.java:600)
    at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.flowAnalysis(CodeContext.java:600)
    at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.flowAnalysis(CodeContext.java:600)
    at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.flowAnalysis(CodeContext.java:600)
    at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.flowAnalysis(CodeContext.java:600)
    at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.flowAnalysis(CodeContext.java:600)
    at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.flowAnalysis(CodeContext.java:600)
    at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.flowAnalysis(CodeContext.java:600)
    at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.flowAnalysis(CodeContext.java:600)
    at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.flowAnalysis(CodeContext.java:600)
    at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.flowAnalysis(CodeContext.java:600)
    .
        .
        .
```

**Solutions I tried to resolve the Issue**

- Caching
- Added checkpoints (it increased the overall processing time from around 20min to 1hr 45min)
- Set the Intelligent Cache Size = 0% for the spark cluster pool.
- Decreased the number of filter conditions in a sigle deletion batch from 5000 to 1500 to 100.
  I tried the above solutions independently as well as combining them with others, but still getting the error.

Below is the mehtod of a class which gets the parameters to delete required records in a for loop.

```
def deleteRecordDelta(self, sql_f_str):
        deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(self.spark, self.path)
        deltaTable.delete(sql_f_str)
```

Expectation is, when a record from source matched multiple records on target side then first the data is deleted in target and then the updated records are inserted. Everything works fine except deletion(most of the time it works but whenever it fails, it fails with the same error).

Please let me know if any other detail is required.

**Edit**

I can't update the existing records with the new ones because the columns on which I am required to join is a **many-to-many type join**, and in this case spark throws an error of merge conflict. That's why for this scenario the existing records are required to be deleted before inserting the new ones.

Comment: Instead of deleting the records when matched you can directly update it.

Comment: Hi @JayashankarGS, the notebook facilitates the upsert when one record from source matches with one record on the sink side. But the columns on which I am required to join is a many-to-many type join, and in this case spark throws an error of merge conflict. That's why for this scenario the existing records are required to be deleted before inserting the new ones.